# Error arises in LazyOutputFormat (Hadoop api 2.x)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

For MultipleOutputs in configurations i am using LazyOutput but it gives error.
I have checked some other examples of lazyoutput they were working and it does not work in program i want.

```
 LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Error is

```
The method setOutputFormatClass(Job, Class<? extends OutputFormat>) in the  
type LazyOutputFormat is  not applicable for the arguments (Job, Class<TextOutputFormat>)
```

while it is same as here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Answer (score 0):

The `OutputFormat` provided as the second argument to `LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass()` must be the same as the actual `OutputFormat` of your job. I'm guessing you're not using `TextOutputFormat`?